# How do I add unit test for [ignoreCase: true] in grails 2.4.5?

Tags: unit-testing, grails

```
public List<User> myMethod(String value, String field) {

        return User.createCriteria().list {
            ne("status", Status.DELETED)
            eq("${field}", value, [ignoreCase: true])
        }
    }
```

I have the code above and it keeps throwing out the error in my unit test:

```
MyService.eq() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, java.lang.String, java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [username, someUsernameYouWant, [ignoreCase:true]]
Possible solutions: grep(), any(), wait(), every(), find(), dump()
```

if remove `[ignoreCase:true]` the test passes. Is there a way to test this  like mock it? because this method is being used by a number of methods inside the same service. I just want the methods who use `myMethod` to friggin pass, because `myMethod` already has an integration test and I'm trying to do a unit tests for the tests that call it..

Answer (score 0):

> How do I add unit test for [ignoreCase: true] in grails 2.4.5?

You could use `HibernateTestMixin`.

Comment: sad I'm using hibernate 3.4

Comment: I didn't know that.  The default hibernate plugin for newly created 2.4.5 apps is `:hibernate4:4.3.8.1`.  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: It's ok. I think somewhere in the past the team decided to use hibernate 3.6 because they had some issues with hibernate 4. Anyhow, I could just move my unit tests to an integration tests, tweak a bit and that would be ok right?